# SDI: Make modal form application topmost

Tags: excel, winforms, modal-dialog, excel-2013, sdi

In my VSTO Add-In written in C# I show a modal form with `form.ShowDialog();`.
The owner of this modal form is (in Excel 2013) the currently active workbook window.

Now the problem:
1) Open a second workbook with Ctrl + N
2) Show the modal form
3) Now **you can change the active worksheet** by using the windows taskbar!!!

Result: You cannot do anything in this workbook window.

**Question: How can I realize a behavior like the standard MessageBox? I will not let my activate another window than it parent window.**

P.S.: Of course I do **NOT** want to set `form.TopMost = true;` because it should not be in front of other applications.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I think I ended in monitoring the ActiveWorkbook after opening my form: If the user changes to another workbook, I change it back to the owner of the modal form.